# What's the grammatical term for this phenomenon?

Tags: grammar, terminology

There is obviously a big essential difference between "no towel" and "there isn't a towel".

I mean, the former cannot probably serve as a complete sentence, while the latter can.

The former can only serve as a subject of a sentence, while the latter contains both subject and a predicate.

So how is this difference named, defined or described in correct grammatical terms?

Comment: I think a better comparison would be between "there is no towel" and "there is not a towel"

Comment: Simchona, I am afraid that would turn around the whole point of my question. Both "there is no towel" and "there is not a towel" can serve as a complete message reporting some fact or information, while "no towel" doesn't report any fact. At least "there is no towel" and "there is not a towel" convey the fact of existence or absence of something, while "no towel" doesn't do that.

Comment: You're comparing apples and oranges, then.

Comment: @simchona - I am not really comparing anything here. I know there is a difference. I just want to know how to define and describe this difference properly in English.

Comment: I'm curious where this question came from. It seems odd to even suggest that there would be a some kind of grammatical relationship between some subject and some full sentence.

Comment: @Jeremy - (1) Once I was quite fascinated with the fact that no language has a strict definition of a sentence. All definitions are quite abstract. Later, when I checked different definitions of a word, I also found that they were rather abstract, too, however, not as abstract as definitions of a sentence. I was really surprised because, on the other hand, in 95 out 100 cases any native speaker can easily tell where a sentence in his native tongue starts and where it ends. So, it's a kind of inner feeling of a sentence that any native speaker has in

Comment: @Jeremy - (2) relation to his language. When I tried looking into this matter more deeply, I found that I myself can easily determine a difference in my language between a sentence and merely a phrase. It's interesting because a sentence may be much shorter than a phrase: "a car at the end of the road" (phrase), "a car is red" (sentence). Having though about it for awhile I kind of figured that a phrase only specifies something, while a sentence is reporting some additional information about something. To me it was like a small discovery, but I did have the presence of mind to realize that

Comment: @Jeremy - (3) I wasn't the first one who realized it - there must have been people before me who not only had discovered it, but even described it using correct grammatical terms in English. Since I didn't know how that phenomenon must be described correctly in English (with the use of correct grammar terms) I came here and asked this question.

Comment: "no towel" no verb.
No woman, no cry!

Comment: My question is closed as "it's difficult to tell what is being asked here" and "cannot be reasonably answered in its current form" after I received a very clear and direct answer to it! :) One of the paradoxes of StackExchange that I have never been able to fathom.

Comment: @brilliant: I believe we closed this is as NARQ because you're trying to compare two phrases which have little to do with each other.

Comment: @simchona - I've already told you here that I wasn't trying to compare anything. All I wanted to know is how to define in English the difference between a sentence and merely a phrase, and 'finiteness' is the answer. You seem not to have gotten the point of this question from the outset.

Comment: @brilliant: I am not the only person who did not understand it. There were four people besides myself who also had to vote to close.

Comment: @simchona - Well, that's okay. Misunderstandings happen. At least one person understood and was able to answer a question that in fact has interested me for quite a long time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the key distinction you want is the 'finiteness' of the expression.  Complete sentences in English generally require a [finite verb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_verb).  According to some (cf. [Klein 1998](http://www.mpi.nl/world/materials/publications/Klein/127_1998_Assertion_and_finiteness.pdf)), the finiteness itself is what grants a sentence the power of assertion.  Consider:

> We ate the pizza.

The above is a sentence, and it has a finite verb, *ate*.  Meanwhile:

> Us eating the pizza.

This expression seems like it might be a sentence at first -- it has a subject, a verb, and an object.  However the verb, *eating*, is nonfinite, and hence the expression as a whole only refers to an event.  It does not state or assert that the event happened, as a sentence would. (Although stating/asserting are not the only options available to a sentence, of course.)  Instead, we can use its reference within another sentence:

> I remember us eating the pizza.

Here, our finite verb, *remember*, takes on the whole expression *us eating the pizza* as its object.

So considering this, a single noun, like *towel*, is generally unable to form a sentence.  (In certain contexts, it might be fine on its own.  However these generally involve an implied unsaid verb.)  "*No towel*" is a more complicated situation, as *no* could have several interpretations based on the function of *towel*.  However it is still apparent that the expression is not a sentence.

Then how do express that a towel exists? (or doesn't?)  We invoke an [existential clause](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existential_clause).  In English, this involves adjoining a form of the copula (*to be*).  In our case we will use the singular present-tense, *is*.  This is finite, so we are well on our way to sentencehood, but we also must observe that English finite verbs require subjects.  Thus we use the [expletive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expletive) pronoun, *there*.  It doesn't have a meaning on its own; it is merely there to satisfy the requirements of a well-formed sentence.  So we now have the power to declare...

> There is no towel.

People have argued about what makes a sentence for a long time.  I just chose a particular argument that I thought had some weight.  Some people would claim that finiteness is irrelevant and there are other key properties that make a sentence valid. (Some rely on verbs, some don't. There are plenty of languages where overt verbs aren't necessary to make a sentence.)  Others would say that the definition of sentence doesn't matter - there are reasons you might say "no towel" even in situations where there was nothing else implied, so we shouldn't draw an arbitrary distinction of what a "sentence" is.  Others still would say that your internal judgement of grammar isn't even as strong as you think, and it is really more like a rough guideline.

To answer your question: there are no concise terms to describe an issue so complicated.  My answer is far from adequate for such a topic, but I hope it put you on a path to figuring out what you wanted to know.  You also may be interested in reading up on [speech acts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speech_act), [grammatical mood](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_mood), [discourse analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discourse_analysis)... (The list could go on endlessly. )

Comment: WOW!!!!! Thank you soooooo much! I didn't even know anything about finite verbs. They ssem to be the core of the matter here. Thank you again!

Comment: Thank you also for other additional information here, which is really very interesting, and for the links!

Answer (score 0):

Is it not about the presence of a VERB in a group of words that makes it a sentence? In all the examples that you give as well, there are no verbs in the phrases, while they are definitely there in the sentences.

So the answer is - the presence  of a verb makes a phrase a sentence.

Comment: I don't think just the presence of a verb is the key here. Take a look: "to know her" (phrase) and "To know her is to love her." (sentence)

Comment: "To know" and "to love" are infinitives, not verbs. The verb is "is" in the second sentence, hence a sentence. HTH

Comment: Infinitives ARE verbs (forms of verbs, to be precise - just like "chooses" in "He chooses books" is a form of a verb "choose", however "chooses" is a verb, just like "choose" is also a verb)